# MIME type not supporting HEIC support type in Wordpress

Tags: uploads, media

I am working on wordpress 5 and want to upload HEIC file type extension. But it doesn't work as it give me this error

**sample1.heic
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.**

But i have added MIME Type support like

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
$mimes['heic'] = 'image/heic';
return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

when i var dump the data it shows it supported that but it dowsn't upload that file
But it still doesn't work

Comment: That looks OK to me. Can you verify your browser is uploading it with that content type? If it is, I'd guess you'll have to debug the upload code to work out why the check is failing.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using, specifically? As far as I can tell, you should be able to upload these. Although keep in mind this format is not for embedding images into web pages.